# Tinymce external plugin in the project directory doesn't work

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

We have our own Tinymce external plugin to add 'accordion' control, which is placed in a directory in the project folder. We simply used,

```
external_plugins : {{'accordion':'/Modules/TinyMCEPlugins/accordion/editor_plugin_src.js'}},
toolbar1 : 'accordion',
```

But, this does not pick the plugin. Is it something wrong with defining the path to the external plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The URL used for external_plugins needs to be a web URL that can be accessed at runtime by the browser.

Guessing that path is not the URL the browser can use. Are there errors in the browser’s console?

Answer (score 0):

You have to host that js file server side.  Convert it into a link, and GET the router.

Example:

```
external_plugins : {"accordian" : "http://example.com/public/TinyMCEPlugins/accordian/editor_plugin_src.js},
```